# Why is my Google Play Store app listing not show in Google search results?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play, google-search-console

I have my app live in Google play store for more than a week now. It is **NOT available** in **Google Search result**, even when searching with the query consisting of "exact app name + Google play store". I can get it easily when searching inside Google play store.

I have added a 1000 word app description, even submitted the app to Google search console.

Am I missing something? But that's not the real issue. I have a third party app store named `https://apkpure.com` in the search results with links to my app on their store.

I have not even added/submitted my app to their store. They seem to have taken everything from the Google Play store (even the screenshots + descriptions which I submitted in Play store). They are stealing the search results to google play store (which is 0). They seem to do a better job at SEO than Google Play store.

What should I do be doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your app is not optimized for search engines. A quick search on Googles Dev website shows some tips to improve your search optimization Failing that, there are guides and resources available to help you improve your search rank. A major factor is popularity though.

In the Google Play store, your app gains new certification based on the number of downloads. (That's why you see the download badge in the app's page) The more downloads and positive reviews, the better search rank you will get.

If you pay to sponsor your app, you an send it to the top of the results page that way, the same way Google search ads work.

As for apkpure, if your app, or those screenshots or descriptions are copyright protected, which they are if you publish them to Google's play store, then apkpure violated copyright. Send Google a complaint, and they will handle it. That is part of why you have to pay 25 dollars for a developer account.

Best of luck to you, I hope that you can improve your search rating, and I hope your dispute is resolved.

Comment: "Improve your search optimization", can you explain a bit. I'm talking about the play store listing. I believe, there are only a few things like titles, short/long descriptions which I need to care about.

Comment: yes, that is true. However, make sure you have keywords in your description, and a good name for your application. That is really the only control you have over search. Google will not list your app in a google search unless:

Comment: B: You pay to sponsor your application, basically letting you pay for your app's search rank...

Comment: hmm. I still fail to understand why the play store link does'not come up at all. I'm not worried about the ranking as of now.

Comment: If you read google developer book, namely about seo and search ranking, it says you have to have a certain amount of downloads to be listed in a web search. I believe it is 1000 downloads, though I may not remember correctly. I have published several apps to the Play Store, and I cannot remember a single one showing up until I had over 1000 downloads.

Comment: Also, I would recommend posting a link to your app, so as to let everyone else see what the problem may be. (it is also a great opportunity for some free marketing)